# Baffled on best method for dropdown list with LONG options

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list

I have a site that uses WooCommerce and the person who set it up has the pick-up location as a product variation. So, first you have to choose a location, and then you can add to cart.

The UX issue is the list is long (maybe 16-18 locations) and each location name is pretty long too. Ex:

> White Bear Lake - Farmer's Market xxxx Washington ave - Tuesdays at 1pm

The question I have is, is using dropdowns the best method? If so, should we attempt to style them a little with JQuery or something, to show separation and breathing room?

Comment: Related: [How do you deal with very long dropdown values?](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/30824/how-do-you-deal-with-very-long-dropdown-values)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the dropdown items easier to parse:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBCXdd.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

[image]

why not use a keyword filter or checkbox this way you are ready pre-determining location criteria

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this: https://select2.github.io/examples.html

[image: Closed]

[image: Open]

Edit: Sorry I misread the question. I thought you met long lists of items, not long names. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Is the expectation that most shoppers will only purchase one item? If not, pickup location as an individual criteria on each item seems inefficient.

Pickup location could be determined during the checkout process. 
The default sorting of locations could be their distance from the billing address, and options could be provided to sort them by neighborhood, distance from another address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find a nice visual presentation of the list, browsing all possible combinations of cities, markets and times is a difficult task for the user and should be supported by the computer. For example, take apart the long names and show a dropdown box for each component. For example:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhMFHn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The options available in the "market"-dropdown should match the selected city. This way, choosing a location becomes a three-step-process in which the user is systematically guided to the desired location.